# Erlang Gen_call vs Gen_cast

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

Erlang OTP said `gen_server:call` is synchronous  and `gen_server:cast` is asynchronous.

after testing, I find `gen_server:call` is synchronous . 
However, `gen_server:cast`  will send message to the mailbox, but did **not** run tasks in parallel.

how can I create **multi processes** to run?

```
-module(example_gen).
-behaviour(gen_server).
-export([start_link/0]).
-export([init/1,
    handle_call/3,
    handle_cast/2,
    handle_info/2,
    terminate/2,
    code_change/3]).

 -export([
      add_bycall/2,
      add_bycast/2
   ]).

   -define(SERVER, ?MODULE).
   -record(state, {}).


add_bycall(Key, Value) ->
   gen_server:call(?SERVER, {bycall, Key, Value}).

 add_bycast(Key, Value) ->
      gen_server:cast(?SERVER, {bycast, Key, Value}).


 example(Key, Value) ->
       timer:sleep(2000),
      io:format("finished [~p, ~p] at [~p] ~n", [Key, Value, erlang:system_time(milli_seconds)]).

start_link() ->
    gen_server:start_link({local, ?SERVER}, ?MODULE, [], []).

init([]) ->
   {ok, #state{}}.


handle_call({bycall, Key, Value}, _From, State) ->
      example(Key, Value),
      {reply, ok, State};
  handle_call(_Request, _From, State) ->
     {reply, ok, State}.


 handle_cast({bycast, Key, Value}, State) ->
    example(Key, Value),
      {noreply, State};
 handle_cast(_Request, State) ->
       {noreply, State}.


handle_info(_Info, State) ->
   {noreply, State}.

 terminate(_Reason, _State) ->
   ok.

 code_change(_OldVsn, State, _Extra) ->
    {ok, State}.
```

running the code

```
[example_gen:add_bycall(K, K) ||  K <-  lists:seq(1, 10) ].

[example_gen:add_bycast(K, K) ||  K <-  lists:seq(1, 10) ].
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Terms *synchronous* and *asynchronous* are orthogonal to terms *serial* and *parallel*. `gen_server:call/2,3` is synchronous with the caller and `gen_server:cast/2` is asynchronous with the caller. The work performed by one `gen_server` is always serial because it is performed by one process.

What terms *asynchronous* and *synchronous* means in this case. If you have code

```
gen_server:call(S, foo),
bar(),
```

Work triggered by `foo` is always performed before `bar/0` and `bar/0` is always performed after work `foo` is finished. Thus `foo` and `bar/0` are **synchronous**. If you have code

```
gen_server:cast(S, foo),
bar(),
```

Work triggered by `foo` can be performed before `bar/0` as well as after or even in parallel on SMP systems. Thus `foo` and `bar/0` are **asynchronous**. The **synchronization** matters between **caller** and **callee**.

Comment: Thanks. it explains a lot.